# Obj-C: Filter array using string (NSPredicate)?

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I'm having the strangest issue. I'm using the below code to filter my array:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scheduleddate contains [CD] %@", @"Wed, Feb 17"];
    
self.dailySchedule = [self.clients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

and it works perfectly. However, the string that I want to filter the array with changes, so I've changed the code to:

```
NSDate *todayIs = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter2.dateFormat = @"EEEE, MMM d, yyyy ";
self.theDateIs = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate: todayIs];
NSLog(@"%@", self.theDateIs);

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scheduleddate contains [CD] %@", self.theDateIs];

self.dailySchedule = [self.clients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

For some reason, when I use the second line of code, even though self.myString is populated (when logged, self.mystring returns Wed, Feb 17), it returns the array empty even though there are results in which the field scheduleddate contains Wed, Feb 17.

Oddly, when I actually write out the string in the first example, it works as it should.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Log `self.myString` right before creating the predicate. Does it really contain the string date?

Comment: @vadian Yes, it does :/

Comment: @vadian See edit above. self.theDateIs comes back populated with the date string, but it still doesn't filter as it does in my first example.

Comment: But `EEEE, MMM d, yyyy` doesn't create `Wed, Feb 17`. it creates `Wed, Feb 17, 2021 ` (with trailing space character) which is not the same.

Comment: `NSArray *dailySchedule2 = [clients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(CustomClassOfObjectsInClients * _Nullable evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) { BOOL passTest = [predicate evaluateWithObject:evaluatedObject]; NSLog(@"%@ %@ passed test predicate: %@", evaluatedObject.scheduleddate, passTest ? "DID" : "did NOT", predicate); return passTest;
}]];` Use this to debug at least.

Comment: @vadian Omg total oversight....UGH! That was the issue. Thank you so much. Clearly I've been staring at this for too long O_O !